# Different index files for different directories on Google Cloud Storage, possible?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

**Problem:** Planning to have my [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)-generated static site served from Google Cloud Storage, but need to serve feeds from `example.com/feed/` for backwards compatibility with WordPress.

**Possible solution:** Say the static feed file (index.xml) is located at `example.com/feed/index.xml`. Then if it's possible to set a different index file for a directory itself (apart from what's set for the bucket e.g. index.html), then people would be able to access my feed from `example.com/feed/`.

But is this possible? If not, is there an alternative I'd be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially create an object in the `example.com` bucket with the name `/feed/`.  That's a bit awkward to think about, and because of the way gsutil works you'd have to do it via the API manually, but it would allow you to serve a feed from `example.com/feed/`.

Alternately, you could simply name your xml content `/feed/index.html`.  If all of your users are indeed visiting `example.com/feed/`, then being able to name the file index.xml is not entirely relevant.  The only special thing you'd need to do is make sure you set the right content type for the `/feed/index.html` object.

Another thing to keep in mind here is that the feed itself should be linked from your main index page with a link like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Awesome Feed" href="http://example.com/path/to/feed.xml" />
```

That gives you the ability to name your feed sanely, and your users can point their feed readers at `http://example.com/` directly -- the reader should be able to follow the link to the feed itself.  That won't help you if you have established readership that expects a wordpress style feed, but you could steer new people in the right direction and deprecate the weird wordpress style after a while.